# How to compile linux-raspberrypi kernel in yocto?

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, bitbake, meta-raspberrypi

I want to build a yocto image with linux-raspberrypi which is present in meta-raspberrypi/recipe-kernel/linux-raspberrypi_x.x.bb

While building image with "bitbake core-image-minimal". It compiles kernel from poky/meta/recipe-kernel/linux-libc-headers_x.x.bb

If I use the following lines in local.conf

```
PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-raspberrypi = "4.9.%"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " linux-raspberrypi"
```

This is the Error I am getting.
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'linux-raspberrypi' (but /home/harris/poky/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)

What else I should write in local.conf to compile kernel from meta-raspberrypi. Also how to stop bitbake fetching kernel directly from poky/meta/recipe-kernel/linux-libc-headers.

I am using 'sumo' branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " linux-raspberrypi"` and try adding to local.conf (or machine.conf) `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-raspberrypi"`.

Comment: Thanks danlor. But now inside recipe-kernel/ two kernel versions are available to build the kernel which I wish.I tried giving "PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-raspberrypi ??= "4.9%" ".But 4.14 kernel is only getting compiled.How to build the kernel that I wish(4.9).

Comment: With "??=" you're setting a "weak" default value, that can (and will) be  overrided by the use of "?=" and/or "=" (check it out; https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#setting-a-weak-default-value). So, just rewrite your sentence in order to assure that the desired version is going to be set:  PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-raspberrypi = "4.9%"